# Return to parent process in Linux

Tags: c, linux, process

I need to make a program which functioning operating 5 processes. A parent forks 4 processes. An each child process registers its own signal handler and pauses. After that its required to write in terminal 0, 1, 2, 3 to start a needed process(using non canonical input). After process executes I need to pause it again and go back to parent process continuing handling 0,1,2,3.

My code:

```
    int pidArray[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        pid_t pid = fork();
        switch (pid) {
            case -1:
                perror("Fork failed");
                exit(1);
            case 0:
                printf("I am the child process with pid: %d\n", (int) getpid());
                //pidArray[i] = (int) getpid();
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        signal(SIGUSR1, capitalizeWord);
                        pause();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        signal(SIGUSR1, invertString);
                        pause();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        signal(SIGUSR1, replaceSymbols);
                        pause();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        signal(SIGUSR1, translateToKOI);
                        pause();
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                pidArray[i] = pid;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        printf("%d ", pidArray[j]);
    }

    for (;;) {
        if (!isatty(0)) { /*Проверка: стандартный ввод - терминал?*/
            fprintf(stderr, "stdin not terminal\n");
            exit(1); /* Ст. ввод был перенаправлен на файл, канал и т.п. */
        };

        char ch;

        tcgetattr(0, &tty);
        savetty = tty; /* Сохранить упр. информацию канонического режима */
        tty.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ISIG);
        tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
        tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &tty);

        read(0, &ch, 1);
        kill(pidArray[(int) ch], SIGUSR1);

        tcsetattr(0, TCSAFLUSH, &savetty);
    }
```

So, I don`t know how to go back to parent process and continue handling user inputs. Also I`m not sure that my implementation is 'okay' cause I`m new to C and process management in Linux and maybe there is an easier way to achieve what I want?

Comment: By "go back to parent process" I guess you mean you want the parent process to do something at that point. To do that you need the child to communicate with the parent. Use an IPC such as `pipe` to achieve that.

Comment: `(int) ch` is not the way to convert the character the user types to the index. It should be `ch - '0'`.

Comment: each child, after it pauses, is going to continue in the loop forking more children.

Comment: @WilliamPursell No, there's a `break` after the `switch` that gets out of the loop in the children.

Comment: The child exits after it does its thing, the parent should use `wait()` to tell when a child has exited.

Comment: @kaylum I mean to return to parent process.

Comment: @Barmar I want the parent process to continue handling the same stuff as it was doing before, I think wait isn`t appropriate in this case, no?

Comment: In that case you don't need to do anything, the `for (;;)` loop will do that.

Comment: @Barmar when I use for loop my process finishes with exit code 30.

Comment: That doesn't happen by itself, that comes from `exit(30)` somewhere in your program.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for help, your comment about converting the character to the index fixed the problem!